# programmatically setup domain node.js app

Tags: node.js, dns, cross-domain

How to add a domain using a node.js admin panel.

Here is the problem statement.

1. User able to add a domain purchased from lets say godaddy, hostgather from anywhere does not matters.
2. The admin panel is executing at digital-ocean.
3. Now the question is how to add a domain to ping a particular part of the app.
   For example,
   This is the official app at : appName.example.com should be ping at [www.purcahseddomain.com](http://www.purcahseddomain.com)

Please please guide me, how to come out.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: that as nothing to do with nodejs u set the A HOST lets say from godaddy with the servers ip u have on digital ocean

Comment: I can understand, it it needs to configure with the nginx too. so is there anything we can do it programatically ?

Comment: ok i get it now(i never used digital-ocean)  you need to set the proxy on nginx with the one that u use on nodejs here is the support from digital ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-node-js-server-with-nginx

Comment: Thanks again, but @bill still we got a problem, we have a lots of domains to configure runtime using an admin panel.

using above link, we can only configure the initial domain.

Comment: i dont really know what options do u have on digitalocean but on nginx u can set different domain names with different proxy paths check if u can create new domain names on digitalocean if not then u need to do them manually inside nginx

Comment: You are right @bill, there is only one way to do manually. There are no other options.